# Ubuntu terminal: "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, ubuntu-11.10

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and get the following error when using the terminal:

```
lee@theia:~$ regedit/home/lee/desktop/Direct3D.reg
bash: regedit/home/lee/desktop/Direct3D.reg: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you enter the command yourself? Or is that what shows up every time you open the terminal? It looks like you are trying to load a `.reg` file, which is for the Microsoft [Windows Registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry), unrelated to Linux. Can you edit your question to provide more details?

Comment: You'll probably get more useful answers if you describe the context in which you got this message or what you were trying to do.

Comment: The error message is sort of self explanatory I thought

Answer (score 5):

It means that the string you entered, `regedit/home/lee/desktop/Direct3D.reg` is not a shell internal. So the shell tried to process it as a command, but was unable to find any command with that name. Because the string contains a `/`, the shell tried to match the part before the slash to a directory and was unable to find such a directory.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you wanted to do `regedit /home/lee/desktop/Direct3D.reg` (see the space after `regedit` command).

That way, the line resembles line that you would use on Windows to import entries to Windows registry. But there's no such thing as Windows registry (and no such thing as Direct3D) in Ubuntu, which (no offense meant) qualifies such attempt for an IT joke.

(Also paths are case-sesitive on Ubuntu and I believe that default desktop folder is named `Desktop`, not `desktop`.)

Comment: Unrelated: You might very well be partially wrong. ([source](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=mesa_gallium3d_d3d11))